# Azure App Proxy and SPA application using MSAL causes:AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application'

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal

Azure App Proxy and SPA application using MSAL causes error: AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type.

I'm trying to access a SPA application using MSAL authentication with Azure AD. For this we have created a App Registration in Azure.

When combining the Azure App Registration with an Azure Application Proxy we get this error:

AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type.

When creating the App Proxy both a Web and SPA application exist in the Application Registration in Azure and I'm thinking this is causing Cross-Origin error as only SPA applications use that method.

Does anyone know how to configure Azure for this scenario?

I have clarified in the image what happens when running both App Registration and APP Proxy. Azure creates both a Web and a SPA app registration with a redirect URI.

[App Registration Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbDiL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application** and used the below endpoint to authorize users:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
&code_challenge=CodeChallenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

[image]

[image]

Now, I tried to generate the **access token** via Postman using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default 
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
code_verifier:S256
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

But I got the **error** like below:

[image]

The error usually occurs if the application is not configured as SPA.

**To resolve the error**, make sure to add the redirect URI under Single page application like below:

[image]

After configuring the above changes, **I am able to generate the access token** like below:

[image]

Make sure to add **origin** under the Headers tab:

[image]

**If still the issue persists**, make sure the application has one application type not both web and SPA configured.

**References:**

[Register single-page applications (SPA) - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration)

[SPA Authorization Code · AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/SPA-Authorization-Code) by Bogdan Gavril

Comment: Thanks!

However, when adding the App Proxy it adds a Web Application with a separate redirect URI. So when running both the App registration and App Proxy I get one Web and one SPA registration.

So I'm wondering how that is to be configured to work?